# Angular is not defined although I already defined it

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I get: 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined" for the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head
         content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="menuController as menuCtrl">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul class="media-list">
                    <li class="media" ng-repeat="dish in menuCtrl.dishes">
                    <div class="media-left media-middle">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="media-object img-thumbnail"
                                 ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                            <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                            <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span></h2>
                        <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
                        <p>Comment: {{dish.comment}}</p>
                        <p>Type your comment:
                            <input type="text" ng-model="dish.comment"></p>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);
        app.controller('menuController', function() {
            var dishes = [
                {
                    name:'Uthapizza',
                    image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                    category: 'mains',
                    label:'Hot',
                    price:'4.99',
                    description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                    comment: ''
                },
                {
                    name:'Zucchipakoda',
                    image: 'images/zucchipakoda.png',
                    category: 'appetizer',
                    label:'',
                    price:'1.99',
                    description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
                    comment: ''
                },
                {
                    name:'Vadonut',
                    image: 'images/vadonut.png',
                    category: 'appetizer',
                    label:'New',
                    price:'1.99',
                    description:'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
                    comment: ''
                },
                {
                    name:'ElaiCheese Cake',
                    image: 'images/elaicheesecake.png',
                    category: 'dessert',
                    label:'',
                    price:'2.99',
                    description:'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
                    comment: ''
                }
            ]
        });
    </script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I really don't understand what is the problem here since I already defined angular.js in the line:

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

I also tried to switch between the two last  ...  blocks and didn't get a different result.

Comment: Are you able to fetch the Angular's library file?

Comment: What do you mean? I can open this file...

Comment: You've included your Module before Angular's library file I guess

Answer (score 0):

Move angular script tag to head. Your inline script

```
var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);
```

gets executed even before angular library gets fetched

Comment: I did it. Now I get an empty web page.

Comment: Instead of 

  `var dishes =`

Use 

  `this.dishes=`

Comment: this one helped :-) Can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

You should put `<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>` before `<script> var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]); ...`.

Comment: I did it. Now I get an empty web page.

Comment: check the console to see what happen.

Answer (score 0):

Move this to head.

```
 <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script> `before` <script> var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]); ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all and especially @Dygen.

The correct code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head
         content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="menuController as menuCtrl">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul class="media-list">
                    <li class="media" ng-repeat="dish in menuCtrl.dishes">
                    <div class="media-left media-middle">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="media-object img-thumbnail"
                                 ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                            <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                            <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span></h2>
                        <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
                        <p>Comment: {{dish.comment}}</p>
                        <p>Type your comment:
                            <input type="text" ng-model="dish.comment"></p>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);
        app.controller('menuController', function() {
            this.dishes = [
                {
                    name:'Uthapizza',
                    image: './images/uthapizza.png',
                    category: 'mains',
                    label:'Hot',
                    price:'4.99',
                    description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                    comment: ''
                },
                {
                    name:'Zucchipakoda',
                    image: 'images/zucchipakoda.png',
                    category: 'appetizer',
                    label:'',
                    price:'1.99',
                    description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
                    comment: ''
                },
                {
                    name:'Vadonut',
                    image: 'images/vadonut.png',
                    category: 'appetizer',
                    label:'New',
                    price:'1.99',
                    description:'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
                    comment: ''
                },
                {
                    name:'ElaiCheese Cake',
                    image: 'images/elaicheesecake.png',
                    category: 'dessert',
                    label:'',
                    price:'2.99',
                    description:'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
                    comment: ''
                }
            ]
        });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

The conclusions are:
 1. There's no need to load angular.min.js in the header block. 
 2. Still, angular.min.js has to be loaded before the "angular.module" line.
 3. variables inside contoller should be declared by this.varname.